# domain of convergence $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{1+t^x}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

let $x \in \mathbb{R} $,

how to determine the domain of convergence $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{1+t^x}$ ,
my attempts :
I known if $x<0$ we get $\frac{1}{1+t^{x}}\rightarrow 1 [ t \rightarrow +\infty] $

Comment: Break $\Bbb R$ into several intervals, then test convergence of the integral.

Comment: Could you fix your last formula? Also, note that even for $x=1$ the integral is divergent. My guess is that it's convergent on $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: I think the OP means $$\frac 1{1+t^x} \to 1 [t \to +\infty].$$

Comment: https://youtu.be/xro7c-mDk1g

Answer (score 1):

If $0<x\leq 1$ then $\int_1^{\infty} \frac 1 {1+t^{x}} \, dt \geq \int_1^{\infty} \frac 1 {t^{x}+t^{x}} \, dt=\infty$ as seen by direct computation. For $x>1$ $\,$ $\int_1^{\infty} \frac 1 {1+t^{x}} \, dt \leq \int_1^{\infty} \frac 1 {t^{x}} \, dt <\infty$ again by direct computation.

Answer (score 0):

Also divergent for x=0 ; If x>0 and  t>=1 then $\frac{1}{(t^x)+ (t^x)}$ <= $\frac{1}{1+t^x}$ <= $\frac{1}{t^x}$ so that  the convergence domain is the same as for $\frac{1}{t^x}$ which you can integrate directly to see that the convergence domain is the interval (1,$\infty$)

Comment: my problem is the demonstration because i can find the result